# How create array bytes in the struct with FieldOffset = 0 ?

Tags: c#, union, marshalling

For example, I created the `byteArray` with 8 bytes and bound it to field `UlongValue` and `DoubleValue`

```
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, Pack = 1, Size = 8)]
    struct ULongStruct
    {
        [FieldOffset(0)]
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 8)]
        public byte[] byteArray;

        [FieldOffset(0)]
        public ulong UlongValue;

        [FieldOffset(0)]
        public double DoubleValue;
    }
```

Unfortunately, I got exception: 
Assembly cause it contains field of object with offset 0, which is incorrectly aligned of overflowed by field which not presenting an object

As solution, I can create

```
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, Pack = 1, Size = 8)]
    struct ULongStruct
    {
        //[FieldOffset(0)]
        //[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 8)]
        //public byte[] byteArray;

        [FieldOffset(0)]
        byte byteArray0;

        [FieldOffset(1)]
        byte byteArray1;

        [FieldOffset(2)]
        byte byteArray2;

        [FieldOffset(3)]
        byte byteArray3;

        [FieldOffset(4)]
        byte byteArray4;

        [FieldOffset(5)]
        byte byteArray5;

        [FieldOffset(6)]
        byte byteArray6;

        [FieldOffset(7)]
        byte byteArray7;

        [FieldOffset(0)]
        public ulong UlongValue;
    }
```

But why I can't use `[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 8)]` for this array?

Comment: Try set specify the ArraySubType  in attribute, like:

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.U1, SizeConst = 8)]

Comment: I checked and get the same exception

Comment: This is a "union", the array reference overlaps the ulong and double in managed code as well.  Which is illegal, the garbage collector cannot know whether the union contains the array or the ulong or double.  So it cannot accurately determine whether the array needs to be garbage-collected.  That's bad, very very bad.   A `fixed` buffer is the best alternative.